# Elements flash up before fading out again

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery code to sort Wordpress articles on a single page, so all articles show on page load, and then when a category link is clicked the non-relevant articles fade out.

It mostly works great, however, when a category link is clicked, all the articles flash up briefly before fading out again leaving the correct ones showing.

**Jquery**

```
$('#filters a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#sortable-portfolio article').fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive", 500);
    });


    $('#sortable-portfolio article:not(.' + filter + ')').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).addClass("inactive", 500);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="category-outdoor">Outdoor</a>
<a  href="#" id="category-live">Live</a>
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, so that only the right articles fade in and out, but I can't figure it out for the life of me!

Comment: $('#sortable-portfolio article').fadeIn will fade in ALL articles, you then fadeOut the ones you dont want

Comment: One small tip if this is jQuery 500 for addClass does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $('#filters a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var filter = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#sortable-portfolio article.' + filter).fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("inactive", 500);
        });


        $('#sortable-portfolio article:not(.' + filter + ')').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).addClass("inactive", 500);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#filters a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#sortable-portfolio article.' + filter).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive", 500);
    });


    $('#sortable-portfolio article:not(.' + filter + ')').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).addClass("inactive", 500);
    });
});
```

this happens because you fadeIn all elements

Answer (score 0):

You might try only fading in the articles having the anchor's ID as a class:

```
$('#sortable-portfolio article .' + filter).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("inactive", 500);
});
```